# How do we know, we are having a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

I am not a mathematician, I always had problem understanding this and perhaps someone can help me.

Let's assume, we have collected data of students height. If our sample is big enough, we know we will have normal distribution.

But my question is: Is there a mathematical way, where we can set an input of the data and find out what distribution we are facing?

What if we do not know, our data is about students height. What if it would be a uniform distributed data... Taking mean and std of this data, could be quiet useless for further investigation.

So is there a way, to at least check if the data we are having has normal distribution or not. And if it is: Could you explain it to me. Thank you

Comment: "If our sample is big enough, we **know** we will have normal distribution."  No, that is not necessarily the case.  Suppose our school is a special school that caters specifically to future horse jockeys and nba stars.  Our data would be skewed, having many people of above average height and many people of below average height, but very few of average height.  It is a common *assumption* (*and one that in practice appears like it could be true*) that our data would be normally distributed as many other things in nature tend to be.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, you are correct. But is there a mathetmatical way to proove we have normal distributed data, beside looking on histogram and make subjective assumtion from it?

Comment: Not unless you can look at every piece of data (and there must be an infinite amount of data).  Of course, we can reasonably determine if we have an **approximation** to a normal distribution.  The reason the normal distribution is so important is the "Central Limit Theorem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which says that is we have any probability distribution with finite mean and standard deviation, then both sum and average of samples will be *approximately* normally distributed (and the larger the samples, the better thee approximation).

Comment: There are many standard tests for the goodness-of-fit of a normal distribution, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test) for example.

Comment: Side note:  there are lots of reasons why height might not be normal, or even unimodal.  Indeed male/female differences might give rise to bimodality...though the two means are so close that it is not clear.  [here](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/00031300265#.XXJR55NKjys) is a reference to an article on this particular subject (not sure if the article itself is available via this link).

Comment: [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/tamre/IsHumanHeightBimodal.pdf) is a link to the article itself.  Note that the distribution the authors find is not actually  bimodal, but "normal" seems like a stretch.